# Define object in clisp

Tags: common-lisp, clisp

I am trying to do a project which includes CLISP. I do not have any knowledge about CLISP and am a complete novice in this language.

Following is the code that is to already given:

```
    #|
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;; POLYMORPHISM

TODO 2a. Define an object "cirle" with variables x,y
    (for  the center of the circle) and radius 
    (to hold the size of the circle). Add a method 
    "area" that returns 2 *pi*radius^2

; run this to peek inside circle
'(xpand (circle))

TODO 2b. Define an object "rectangle" with variables x1,x2,y1,y2
    that all default value of 0. Add
    a method "area" that returns the area of that rectangle
TODO 2c. Show the output from the following test

|#

(defun polymorphism()
  (let ((sum 0)
        (all (list (circle :radius 1) 
                   (rectangle :x2 10 :y2 10)
                   (circle :radius 2))))
    (dolist (one all)
      (incf sum (send one 'area)))
    (print `(polymorphism ,sum))))

; to run, uncomment the following
'(polymorphism)

#|
```

I have to create an object for circle and rectangle which has attributes and a method.

For the circle, this is what I have already tried:

```
(defthing
  circle
  :has  ((x 0) (y 0) (radius 0))
  :does ((area (radius)
                   (2 * (22/7) * radius))
         ))
```

For the rectangle, this is what I have already tried:

```
(defthing
  rectangle
  :has  ((x1 0) (y1 0) (x2 0) (y2 0))
  :does ((area
                   ((x1-x2) * (y1-y2) * radius))
         ))
```

Is that all I will need or do I have to add anything for the circle and rectangle methods to work?

Comment: Where does `defthing` come from?  Some educational system?  Can't help you with that.  However, you can help yourself: the instructions tell you what to run to try it out.  Maybe there are even helpful error messages.

Comment: defthing is defined in the script itself. Is there any way I can talk to you somewhere else and get some help?

Comment: Careful: `CLISP` is a *Common Lisp* implementation. Please use the abbreviation `CL` for Common Lisp, the language.

Comment: No one can help you without at least the following two pieces of information: 1. What the definitions of `defthing` and `send` are; and 2. What are the errors you are getting. Stack overflow requires a minimal, reproducible complete example however this is not reproducible or complete.

Answer (score 2):

Common Lisp does not have infix  arithmetic. All arithmetic is done by calling functions and calling functions is done by writing an opening paren, the function name, the arguments, then a closing paren.

Where you write:

```
                (area (radius)
                   (2 * (22/7) * radius))
```

You probably meant to write:

```
                (area (radius)
                   (* pi radius radius))
```

(Assuming you are trying to calculate the radius and not approximating the circumference)

Answer (score 1):

`defthing` isn't a built-in macro. We build objects with `defclass`. There is a tutorial: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/clos.html

```
(defclass person ()
  ((name
    :initarg :name
    :accessor name)
   (lisper
    :initform nil
    :accessor lisper)))
```

Create an object of that class:

```
(make-instance 'person :name "me" )
```

Methods are created with `defmethod`:

```
(defmethod greet (obj)
  (format t "Are you a person ? You are a ~a.~&" (type-of obj)))
```

They can specialize on the type of the argument:

```
(defmethod greet ((obj person))
  (format t "Hello ~a !~&" (name obj)))
```